# PHP - Drop in/out of PHP dynamically?

Tags: php

I'm trying to find an solution to drop out and in PHP dynamically. Reason: I want to have a script generate plain PHP code *and* keep the possibility to execute the code.

The following statement works fine:

```
<? 
    if ($statement == true) { 
        ?>echo "hello";<? 
    } else { 
        echo "hello"; 
    } 
?>
```

I would love to prevent the double work. The following will give an error obviously, but I'm wondering if there is an other way to do exactly what I need to do?

```
<? if ($statement == true) { ?> } echo "hello"; { <? } ?>
```

Comment: eh, I don't get your question, if you need to `echo "Hello";` in both cases, then why have a if clause? - And I have a hard time believing that your first if-clause works since the echo inside it isn't wrapped in the php tags.

Comment: I think he's trying to echo "hello" in the secnod case, but to echo "echo "hello";" in the first one: to show the code that produces the output. eval() comes to mind.

Comment: `readfile(__FILE__); die();`

Comment: In what universe does that code ___work___

Comment: **Never use short tags tags ('<? ')**. Always use: 1) `<?php` if using logic or more than one line of PHP. OR 2) `<?=` (short echo tags) when outputing strings when using PHP as a 'templating' language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval) function. It is able to parse a string and execute any contained php code:

```
<?php
    $code = 'echo "hello";';
    if($statement)
        echo $code;  //print
    else
        eval($code); // execute
?>
```

For security reasons you should verify the generated code, especially when it contains user input.

Answer (score 0):

I know some people are going to say this is a terrible answer and that you should never use eval, but if used properly (not running user inputted code) it is secure.

I suggest looking into the [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function of php. you can have it execute code in a string.

So something like this would work:

```
$code = 'echo "hello";';
if($statement == true)
  $code = "?>".$code."<?php";
eval($code);
```